Why: python3.11: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.11.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
On Ubuntu, Python3.11 cannot find libpython3.11.so.1.0.
Here is my system information:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

On my system, I have installed python3 and python3-dev, with versions python3.12.3.At the same time, I compiled Python 3.12.7 using the following compilation instructions:
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-lto=full --enable-shared
make
make altinstall

Then everything is normal, here are the details:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdbd726000)
libpython3.12.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0 (0x000077c52ea00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000077c52e600000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x000077c52f165000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000077c52f26a000)

However, when I need to install other versions of Python, such as Python3.11.10, issues arise.
The compilation configuration is identical to that of Python3.12, but the following problem occurs:
python3.11: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.11.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I resolved the issue by doing the following:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

However, I don't understand why this problem occurred. Was there a configuration error somewhere?
Here is the detailed information:
> ll /usr/local/lib/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Oct  3 13:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Apr 24 18:47 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 Oct  3 13:42 libpython3.11.so -> libpython3.11.so.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 25185720 Oct  3 13:42 libpython3.11.so.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 Oct  2 16:19 libpython3.12.so -> libpython3.12.so.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 31234664 Oct  2 16:19 libpython3.12.so.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    15088 Oct  3 13:42 libpython3.so*
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Oct  3 13:42 pkgconfig/
drwxr-xr-x 39 root root     4096 Oct  3 13:42 python3.11/
drwxr-xr-x 40 root root     4096 Oct  2 16:19 python3.12/

The default environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty.
Other:
> readelf -d /usr/local/bin/python3.12

Dynamic section at offset 0x2db8 contains 28 entries:
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpython3.12.so.1.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x115c
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x3da8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x3db0
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x3b0
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x548
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x3f8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              222 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x3fb8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x738
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x678
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             192 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x648
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x626
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

readelf -d /usr/local/bin/python3.11

Dynamic section at offset 0x2db8 contains 28 entries:
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library:[libpython3.11.so.1.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x115c
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x3da8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x3db0
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x3b0
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x548
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x3f8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              222 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x3fb8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x738
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x678
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             192 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x648
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x626
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0


Alright, I've found the root cause of all the issues: after compiling, you need to run sudo ldconfig.

When does the error occur? During compilation (the make step) or during executing (i.e., running python 3.11)?

A missing sudo ldconfig is not the root cause. If both 3.12 and 3.11 get installed in /usr/local/ and libpython3.12.so is found, then libpython3.11.so should also be found.

There is the possibility that for Python 3.12, the build system has been changed to use an rpath to point to libpython in its installed location, while this doesn't happen for Python 3.11. Then this particular error occurs if /usr/local/lib is not in ld.so.conf. If that is the case, that may be visible somewhere in the build output.

@9769953 I just recompiled Python, and no errors occurred. Throughout the compilation process, there were no warnings or errors, so this should not be an issue with Python.

@9769953 However, the problem is indeed strange. I am certain that /usr/local/lib has always been included in the ld.so.conf configuration (/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf). After discovering this, I tried to rebuild the cache, and the problem was resolved.

@9769953 We consider the following scenario: assuming python312 is available but python311 is not, and their dependencies are located in the same place, what issues could cause this? In fact, due to the presence of the system Python, it is difficult for me to determine if Python312 is functioning properly.

That's a completely different question, right? Whether Python 3.12 is functioning properly. And which 3.12 are you talking about then? The newly installed one?

Do note that you found that your newly installed Python 3.12 is linked with /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0, not with /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.12.so. So I'd say it's properly installed and working, and possibly an rpath is used to link with its so library. (In fact, ldd /usr/bin/python3.12 on my 24.04 installation doesn't not even show a libpython, so I think the system version is statically built).

@9769953 You are correct, this is unrelated to the system Python. I've added some information, but it also seems that the issue might not be related to rpath.

Curious, but could you check /usr/local/bin/python3.12 --version?

@9769953 Yes, I checked, the system Python is 3.12.3, python3.12 is 3.12.7, and python3.11 is 3.11.10.
